# Can't insert goal in Google Management beta API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have a problem with goal insert function (I have beta API whitelist for my project). Based on the documentation, insert function for goals should have 4 parameters: account, profile, property ID and goal object. Function with those parameters is returning this error:

[image]

Here is the main code in PHP:

```
...
$goal = $analytics->management_goals->get($_POST["accIdOrig"], 
$_POST["propIdOrig"], $_POST["viewIdOrig"], $_POST["goalIdOrig"]);      
$analytics->management_goals->insert($_POST["accIdDest"], $_POST["propIdDest"], $_POST["viewIdDest"], $goal);
echo json_encode($goal);
...
```

Omitting one of those parameters still returns an error.

Also, I would like to ask how can I query smart goals? Is it possible to copy&paste goals to a specific position (slot)? If so, how can I know if the slot is really empty when smart goals are not showing? Or will API insert goal into the first empty slot? GA has limited slots of 20 goals...

Answer (score 0):

This error likely refers to accountId, profileId and webPropertyId fields inside the [Goals](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals#resource) resource, not the parameters of insert() operation. Since you are re-using an existing goal resource by calling "management_goals->get" and passing the result directly to "insert", this is how these fields end up being populated.

Comment: I want to call the `get()` function to extract goal from a view and `insert()` it into another one. In other cases (metrics, dimensions, filters, ...) this approach works. I don't understand why this doesn't work also in case of goals. The error is returning that values must NOT be set for field account, web property or view ID, which is wierd...

Comment: Did you try to set empty values for accountId, profileId and webPropertyId fields inside the Goals resource before calling insert()? Does it help?

Comment: In this case (empty profileId) PHP script file returns 200 but in console I have error "parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"